# If I assume something to be true and it gives right result. Can I say that my assumption is also right?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

I learnt about matrix this week. In our textbook there is a proof of **(AB)<sup>-1</sup>=B<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>-1</sup>**
However I believe it was a lengthy one, so I looked for a shorter one on my own and came up with this:

*Let us assume this is true which means:*
**(AB)<sup>-1</sup>= B<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>-1</sup>**

*Post Multiplying A we get:*
**(AB)<sup>-1</sup>*A = B<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>-1</sup>A**
**(AB)<sup>-1</sup>*A = B<sup>-1</sup>**

**B<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>-1</sup>A = B<sup>-1</sup>

B<sup>-1</sup>= B<sup>-1</sup>**
*We know this is true hence our assumption was also right.*

Is this a correct prove?

Comment: No. False assumptions can prove anything, so in particular they can prove true things.

Comment: But look at your  example.  Can you follow the steps backwards?  That would certainly achieve your goal.

Comment: Assume $1=2.$ Multiplying by $0$ we get $0=0.$ "We know this is true hence our assumption was also right"? Moreover, the usual proof that *if* $A$ and $B$ are invertible *then* so is $AB$ and its inverse is $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is not that lengthy (not lengthier than what you wrote).

Comment: Thank you @lulu It works.

Comment: Gratitude to all of you